# swift 3.0 coreData Subclass

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

Now the NSMangededObject SubClass is automatically generated
where do I put the code that I usually put in the subclass file ?

now I am missing this file

```
public class IneedToDoStuffHere: NSManagedObject {

 }
```

do I just create my own swift file and do?

```
 extension IneedToDoStuffHere{


 }
```

I am kinda confused about this new setup.

Comment: or should i just change the Codegen to Manual/None and do it the old way ?

Comment: You will lose the compile time checking of the symbols if you use another file. Until you run these errors shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code in of the classes. After creating an Entity, when we create a NSManagedObject class, Two classes are generated.

1. ClassName+CoreDataClass.swift

import Foundation
import CoreData

```
@objc(ClassName)
public class ClassName: NSManagedObject {
    func add(){
        var obj = ClassName()
        emp.username = "John"
        emp.email = "john@example.com"
        Employee.fetchRequest()
    }
}
```

2. ClassName+CoreDataProperties.swift

import Foundation
import CoreData

```
extension ClassName{

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ClassName>{
        return NSFetchRequest<ClassName>(entityName: "ClassName");
    }

    public var username: String?
    public var email: String?   
}
```

You can write the code in any of the class. As you the other class is an extension so the code written in the ClassName+CoreDataProperties.swift, will work.

But, You should write the code in ClassName+CoreDataClass.swift file, as it separate out the properties and class.

Thanks

Comment: well this is what I used to do, but my question is now that the coredata is changed do i still do the same thing or just write an extension to auto generated subclasses

Comment: Yes that will also work fine. But if you have more properies/attributes then you can separate out with different class.

Comment: @EricYu, CoreData now separates rewritable code from constant for you. File `+CoreDataProperties` with `extension` and `@NSManaged` properties is for autogenerated CoreData code. And `+CoreDataClass` is for your personal code.